# Como criar um overflow horizontal?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Seguinte, estou editando um site usando wordpress e tenho algumas limitações quanto ao uso do html e etc, queria criar um overflow horizontal, para que ao inves de ficar como na imagem abaixo, o scrollbar  fosse horizontal ao inves de vertical.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

para deixar assim, com a rolagem vertical, o css é:

```
.scrolling-wrapper {

max-height: 500px;
 overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

o scrolling-wrapper seria a div que estão todos esses produtos, e todos os produtos possuem a classe .card-destq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não sei exatamente a estrutura HTML que vc tem ai do *containe* e das `div`s. Mas aqui tem um exemplo simples feito com `flexbox` que pode te ajudar.

```css
.box {
 min-width: 200px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: red;
 margin: 1rem;
}
.scrolling-wrapper {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrolling-wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```